# PHP cutting off starting and ending zero

Tags: php

I have found plenty of ways to add a zero to one side of a string and also  get rid of the zeroes, but the issue I am having is my numbers come back like this:

```
 10
 6.9
```

And I need to keep zeroes on either side of decimal place like this:

```
 10.00
 06.90
```

now excuse me if i am just not searching with the correct terminology but i cant find the answer here

i need to keep leading and trailing zeroes intact

Comment: http://php.net/sprintf

Comment: str_pad() and number_format() could also be useful.

Comment: that is leading zeroes i need leading and trailing to stay intact

Comment: Yes - but the answer is the same either way; if you need the leading or trailing zeroes you're not really dealing with a number - but a string representing that number.

Comment: could you point out how?  its not decimals either, as i said i know how to add a zero, i'm trying to keep the ones i already have

Comment: If you're not changing anything in the string - just ensure it's always a string: `$n = '06.90'; echo $n; // outputs 06.90`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$out=number_format($number,2,'.','0');

echo ($out<10)?"0".$out:$out;
```

By using the number_format function you can get the decimal values after dot and ternary operator for make the round with decimal values

Comment: this could be the answer.

Comment: could you edit that to be formatted?  thanks

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.